# Move database physical location using a loop for database names. MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a main database and several other databases that store documents in them.

I am trying to figure out a way to write a loop in my database move script that dynamically loops through the document databases and include them in my script however the amount of databases aren't fixed. For example I could have one documents database called AppDocuments1 or multiple document databases e.g. AppDocuments1, AppDocuments2, AppDocuments3 and so on.

Could someone help me with creating a loop that automatically loops the all databases dynamically so I can include them in my database script.

I have access to the number of databases there are in a field in the main product database. e.g. NoOfDocumentDatabases : value = 6 would indication 6 document databases all named as above.

Comment: This, in truth, sounds like you have a design flaw if I am honest, and you should be using a single database with all the documents, and a column to denote the "(database)number"

Comment: *"Could someone help me with creating a loop that automatically loops the all databases dynamically so I can include them in my database script."* You can try Aaron Bertrand's [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) or my [A CURSOR free version of sp_msforeachdb](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/)

Comment: True that. We are distributing a product where we are using SQL Server express edition as part of that package and the size limitation of 10GB is the reason why we split it up.

Comment: It's about time that you should really be investing in a paid version of SQL Server then.

Comment: Do you have to loop through the databases? All physical for for all databases on the instance are in sys.master_files.